# FOR FETCH ONLY with FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY?

Tags: db2

Is there any performance benefit to adding FOR FETCH only to a DB2 query that already has FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY in it, or does the FETCH FIRST X ROWS syntax already include all the benefits of FOR FETCH ONLY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two clauses have completely different purposes and behaviour.

[`FOR FETCH ONLY`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059219.html), alternatively `FOR READ ONLY` tells the query optimizer that you do not intend to update or delete any of the fetched rows, so it can do more efficient retrieval of rows (blocking) and reduce the amount of resources required to maintain the cursor state.

[`FETCH FIRST x ROWS ONLY`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059212.html) is intended to tell the optimizer that you are not interested in reading the entire result set, however large it might be. This might cause the optimizer to choose the access plan that results in first rows to be returned to the client faster.

You should use the clauses (one or the other, or both) when they suit your goal. Please read the linked documentation pages for more details.